# SSH from Windows 10 to Windows 10 port 22 time out, and password issue

Tags: ssh, windows-10

So I have been toying around with this for a week now and it is driving me bananas. I have the native Windows 10 SSH server and client installed on both machines. Most of the time when I try to connect I get "ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.8 port 22: Connection timed out" when I realized it might be my firewall I disabled it and tried again only to get "ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.8 port 22: Connection refused". The only time I have gotten closer is when using a Ubuntu VM, but then when I am prompted for a password none work, I assume that has to do with the rsa key that I have yet to establish.

How can I get either (Preferably Both) of these connections to work?
Can two Windows 10 PCs even SSH to each other?
Is there a solid tut out there that I should turn to?

I would be thankful for any help on this problem.
Thank you for your time

N/A

Comment: I had the same issue. After modification of security group, it worked.
I found the solution : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8BAAc0G1Yk

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the optional Windows 10 feature OpenSSH Server (sshd) and the corresponding ssh client to make connections between two Windows 10 PCs. You can actually use any ssh standard client to connect, i.e. ssh from Linux.

When you install the "OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)" from the optional feature settings in Windows it will also automatically create a firewall rule in the Inbound Rules folder of the Windows Defender Firewall and activate the rule. This should make it possible to connect with any ssh client to your PC.

After the installation check the following:

- The Windows Service called **OpenSSH SSH Server** is started and running, it is set to manual start as default so it will not be running unless you have started it.
- The inbound firewall rule **OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)** is enabled in **Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security**

If these are active you should be able to use `ssh MACHINENAME` from a shell, command prompt or terminal on another PC to connect to the PC running the SSH server.

When using a Microsoft Account the user name might display a shorter version of the username when you sign-in but the password would be the same as your Microsoft Account.

Comment: I have this set up, see the rule in firewall, can ssh to localhost and the NAT ip on the same machine, but still can't connect from another machine on the lan. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem. In my case, I fixed it in the services settings on windows. Make sure that the startup options of the Open SSH Agent and Open SSH Server services are set to automatic and that you start the services. At best, do a reboot afterwards. Again check whether sshd and ssh-agent in the services tab in task manager are running. Then, it should work.